# how to set the listview format as picture below? I can show all the data in database, But It is not what i want

Tags: android, listview

Do y'all know how to make those Information in the one box instead of like picture below? Sorry about that I don't know how to express myself. What I mean is  make " 1, A0010001 , 16/08/2018 ,John,100,Donation,16/08/2018" In One box, and the Id starts with "2" should be in other box... I'm wondering wow to do it? Is there any way to do? I shared an example in the post below. Please refer there, Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Here is my Code**

```
if(data.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(Summary_Page.this,"No database",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                    theList.add(data.getString(0));
                    theList.add(data.getString(1));
                    theList.add(data.getString(2));
                    theList.add(data.getString(3));
                    theList.add(data.getString(4));
                    theList.add(data.getString(5));
                    theList.add(data.getString(7));
                    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,theList);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
```

It will show all data in the listview. But How do I arrange it like the picture below?

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a custom list view or Recycler view with cardView to show the data as you want. Also you have to put the adapter of the list view out of while loop.

```
else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                    theList.add(data.getString(0));
                    theList.add(data.getString(1));
                    theList.add(data.getString(2));
                    theList.add(data.getString(3));
                    theList.add(data.getString(4));
                    theList.add(data.getString(5));
                    theList.add(data.getString(7));

                }
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<> 
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,theList);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
```

instead of using simple adapter you have to use custom list view adapter with base adapter

Comment: Okay,Thank you. I'll search for youtube tutorial~